# Flutter how to add an item every Nth time to a listview in streambuilder

Tags: flutter, admob

Am trying to place ads in my flutter app that displays a stream of items from firebase. To do this am using the insert method but am getting an error every time; `error: The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'.`

This is how am going about it

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            //stream: getposts(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>>snapshots) {
              var adcode=Text(" Ad goes here");
              snapshots.data.insert(2, adcode);

              return Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                   //listview items)


)
```

Any ideas how I can fix the error above or an alternative way to place ads every Nth item in between items from a streambuilder? Am using Google Admob package for the ads

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put a `Text` instance where a `DocumentSnapshot` is expected. Probably here: `snapshots.data.insert(2, adcode);`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to create a new `List` and then modify it's content like this.

```
var adcode = Text(" Ad goes here");
List<dynamic> finalList = snapshots.data;
finalList.insert(2, adcode);
// Use this finalList to build your Widget.
```

Then if you are using a `ListView.builder`, whenever you reach that `nth` index, you can read the data and use it differently since the data at that index is going to be a `Text` widget and not your `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: could you please provide further example on how to  use finalList in Listview

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best approach but this is what I will choose.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({this.title});
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

List<String> display = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four",
  "Five",
  "Six",
  "Seven",
  "Eight",
  "Nine",
  "Ten"
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: display.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          if (index % 2 == 0 && index != 0) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

hopefully, this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Hey Aashar, this has been helpful except for  little problem. where my listview currently contains 5 items. After followin your method. 2 of those items are replaced by the widet in the inserted code. In this case green container

Comment: Yes, that's why there is a column that contains a new widget and the other widget.

Comment: How can I make all my original widgets visible?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question.